# Generating ArcGIS Report with images based on field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, image, reports

I'm currently trying to generate a report through ArcGIS 10.2.2 based on my attribute table in which one of the field is a photo links field. I would like to have them show up as pictures rather than links in my report, but so far I have not had any success with it.

Answer (score 2):

From the esri [help pages...](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Adding_images_to_reports/004v00000012000000/)
When you are in the edit report layout page.

[image: report designer]
Select picture under element on the left hand side and add it to whatever location you want on your report.  When you click on the box, on the right hand side there is a place to add your source which you have 3 choices:

[image: sourcedialog]

**Source 1:** choose a field You can choose any Raster or Text field as the source of an image in your report. If you choose a Text field, the field values need to be the path to the image file.

Source 2: use a file path to a local, network, or web location. You can assign the source of a picture element to be a file path to an image. The file path can be stored locally on disk, network and online.

Source 3: use a static image

As long as the link is updated to your local drive where the image is stored, the image should show up  in the report for the entire column.